# textarea display from database with gaps at the front

Tags: html, mysql

I've got a text area where members can update their about me profile. When it goes into it I have set it so it displays what they already have in their profile. But, when they go to edit it, it's got a load of spaces at the beginning before the first word.

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="25" name="aboutme" id="aboutme" >
    <?php echo $user_data['aboutme']; ?>
</textarea>
```

It's being called from the database using the `$user_data` variable

That's my code; can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can do:

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="25" name="aboutme" id="aboutme" ><?php echo $user_data['aboutme']; ?></textarea>
```

To get rid of the "hardcoded" whitespace in your HTML, and make sure $user_data['aboutme'] doesn't contain whitespace in its value, either by trimming it in SQL or when echoing it.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt realize if i break it in the html code it would output white-spaces. Thank you :)